# maven central repository replacement

Tags: maven

because of my corporate security policy i can not use internet at my development platform so i am getting error while using maven in my java projects. as i see it causes from not accessing https://repo.maven.apache.org/

i have searched to find out to run maven offline but solutions i have found not worked for me.

i need step by step explanation:

which files do i need to download (with download url)?

where do i need to put them at my local file system (i do not have alternative repositiory server)?

how should i change pom file to replace central repository with local filesytem path?

thanks,

Comment: Start using a repository manager and let your company handle this...afterwards you can use the repository manager ...

Comment: Maven really likes an internet connection.  Are you allowed to use a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to set up a Nexus or Artifactory inside your company. This can be used from Maven then. This Nexus/Artifactory needs to be equipped with the necessary artifacts or a connection to MavenCentral.

You cannot "manually" download Maven.

If you have a machine that is only temporarily disconnected from the internet, you can use `dependency:go-offline`, but this is probably not what you want.